# P/Invoke - how access doubles using result of a c function that returns an address to an array of doubles

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

How to get float array from the function fann_run()

This the C version of it.

```
fann_type *calc_out;
fann_type input[2];
struct fann *ann = fann_create_from_file("xor_float.net");
input[0] = -1;
input[1] = 1;
calc_out = fann_run(ann, input);
printf("xor test (%f,%f) -> %f\n", input[0], input[1], calc_out[0]);
fann_destroy(ann);
```

I am trying to this in c#

```
[DllImport("fannfloat.dll", EntryPoint = "fann_run")]
public static extern IntPtr fann_run(IntPtr _ann, float[] _input);

IntPtr ann = FANN.fann_create_from_file("Arial.net");
IntPtr result = FANN.fann_run(ann,input600);
```

Now i want to access the floats using 'result'.
How can i do this ?

Comment: How do you know how long the array is? Or is it actually just a pointer to a single float?

Comment: The given nn network is initialized with 600 input neurons and 7 output neurons, so it should give me an array of length 7 in the same way the c example which give an array of length 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Marshal.Copy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a53bd6cz.aspx) to copy the values from unmanaged memory into a managed array if you know the number of elements:

```
float[] output = new float[7];
Marshal.Copy(result, output, 0, output.Length);
```

Don't forget to free `result` when you're done.